# LocationServices.SettingsApi calling onActivityResult with RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

I have been struggling with new `LocationServices.SettingsApi` in one particular case.

Lets assume on your device settings are as **Location Turned ON** and **Airplane Mode is On**. Now if you check for the `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` using `LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings` it will give the status as 6 `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED`.

If I get `RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` I call `startResolutionForResult` which shows the new settings prompt asking user to enable Wifi scan and other things. If press **YES** on this `onActivityResult` is called with resultCode as `RESULT_CANCELED` this should have been called with resultCode as `RESULT_OK`

Comment: Please explain why down voted? You can atleast explain why this behaviour is happening.

Comment: (I'm not an original down voter and I added my vote to "reset" the downvote) wow, if this is true, it seems bug in Google Play Services. You'd better report to Google, I don't think anyone here can help you :/

Comment: For a meantime (I mean until Google fix this bug) you can workaround by checking http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON

Comment: Did you solve this? I got into the same issue. It happen only on some samsung device (ex: galaxy S3).